# Is there a feature in blender similar to Unity's render textures?

Tags: texturing

I want a texture/shader in blender that displays the camera's view. is this feature possible?

Comment: Do you mean 'shades surfaces differently when they're visible through the camera'?

Comment: I think he means like a live "video screen" displaying camera view

Comment: No this is not possible trivially. You have to use a different view layer with a different camera and composit it afterwards. However the aspect ratio of both cameras has to be the same so this is not really usable